# Solving: $\underset{\alpha}{\text{min}} \; || \left( b - A(\alpha \circ x ) \right) ||_{2}^{2}$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus, gradient-descent, hadamard-product

I want to solve the following minimization problem:

$$ \underset{\alpha}{\text{min}} \; || \left( b - A(\alpha \circ x  ) \right) ||_{2}^{2} $$

where $\alpha, x \in \mathbb{C}^{N}$ and $b \in \mathbb{C}^{M}$ and $A \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times N}$ and $\circ$ denotes the Hadamard product.

This can be done using gradient descent. Since the objective function is convex and analytic, we just need to find the $\alpha$ such that the gradient $\frac{d}{d \alpha} = 0$

To start, we rewrite the objective as:

$$ f(\alpha) = || \left( b - A(\alpha \circ x  ) \right) ||_{2}^{2} = ( b - A(\alpha \circ x  ))^{H}( b - A(\alpha \circ x  ))  = \epsilon^{H} \epsilon$$

Now we can compute the differential:

$$ f = \epsilon: \epsilon $$
$$ df = 2\epsilon : d\epsilon = 2 \epsilon : d(b - A(\alpha \circ x  )) = -2\epsilon: A( x \circ d \alpha)$$
$$ df = -2 A^{H} \epsilon :  x \circ d \alpha$$
$$ \boxed{df = -2 A^{H} (\epsilon \circ x) :   d \alpha}$$

---

Now this is where I am confused. According to the first identification theorem for differentials, the gradient should be:

$$ \boxed{\frac{df}{d \alpha}  = -2 (\epsilon \circ x)^{H} A} $$

And so the gradient descent update is:

$$  \boxed{\alpha_{k+1} = \alpha_{k} + 2 \mu (\epsilon \circ x)^{H} A} $$

However, when minimizing $|| b-Ax ||_{2}^{2}$ wrt $x$, the derivative should be:

$$ \frac{df}{d x}  = 2 A^{T}(b - Ax)$$

So where did I go wrong? What should the gradient be?

Comment: Note that $(A^H\epsilon\circ x) \ne A^H(\epsilon\circ x)$

Comment: So is that where I am going wrong? So then we would have $df = -2A^{H} \epsilon \circ x : d \alpha$ which would mean that the derivative is $ \frac{df}{d \alpha} = (-2A^{H} \epsilon \circ x)^{H} = -2 \epsilon^{H} A \circ x^{H}$ ?

Comment: Why do you want to solve this directly in $\alpha$ rather than minimizing with respect to $(\alpha \odot x)$ then solving for $\alpha$? The only difference comes in when $x$ has zero entries. In that case, you can simply delete columns of A corresponding to places where $x$ has zero.

Comment: @Alex Because I am boxed in by my original formulation of the problem. Myopia induced by my own thinking. That is the only reason.

Comment: @Alex Actually $x$ will have zero entries. Could you write an answer detailing that idea?

Comment: It would be pretty clear if you work out a simple example (just write out some 4x4 matrix and see what happens when $x$ has zero entries). Essentially, it means that you don't get to touch some of the columns of $A$ in approximating $b$, so you lose some rank.

Comment: @Yea I wrote it out. What is the significance of loosing rank though? The system will be overdetermined after eliminating the columns.

Comment: The significance is that the system becomes more overdetermined if it was already overdetermined. It basically just changes the least squares problem that you solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the matrices
$$\eqalign{X &= {\rm Diag}(x),\quad Y &= AX \\}$$
Reformulate the objective function to get rid of the Hadamard product (and the minus sign).
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= (Y\alpha-b)^*:(Y\alpha-b) \\
d\phi
 &= (Y\alpha-b)^*:Y\,d\alpha \,\,\;+\; (Y\alpha-b):Y^*\,d\alpha^* \\
 &= Y^T(Y\alpha-b)^*:d\alpha \;+\; Y^H(Y\alpha-b):d\alpha^* \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\alpha} &= Y^T(Y\alpha-b)^*,\quad
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\alpha^*} = Y^H(Y\alpha-b) \\
}$$
Set the gradient (it doesn't matter which one) to zero and solve for the optimal value.
$$\eqalign{
Y^HY\alpha &= Y^Hb \\
\alpha &= (Y^HY)^{-1}Y^Hb \\&= Y^+b \\
}$$
Notes:

$\quad(b-Y\alpha)=\epsilon\;$ in your terminology

$\quad Y^+\;$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse

Or you can avoid the gradient calculations completely by noting that you want the least-squares solution of a linear system, i.e.
$$Y\alpha = b \quad\implies \alpha = Y^+b $$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I appreciate you showing the calculations to help me learn what I did wrong.